# Boot Session_Init taking forever Win10

Tags: windows-10, boot

So for some reason my boot is taking forever, like 353 seconds. I used xbootmgr to trace what is going on but I am not an expert. Can someone take a look and let me know what is taking all the time?

[image: WPA Screen Shot]

The link to the entire log is here if that helps: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtOdmtev4QgBwR5AZHgRe-1sJpVd

Comment: any update on your issue?

Comment: Thanks for the reply I would not have been able to find the issue without your help. I am trying to track down why the registry is not initializing quickly. I have attempted to 'clean' the registry with CCleaner but so far it has made no difference in boot times. Interestingly, I cant find anything on the web about the InitializeRegistry command so its tricky to figure out what is slowing it down. Interestingly, I backed up my system and then did a 'reset' and that fixed the problem, so at least I know it is not a hardware problem, but when I restore the system the problem remains.

Comment: share a new trace, this time use [WPRUI.exe](https://superuser.com/a/1205327/174557), here the wait data are included in the trace when you select CPU. maybe I see what causes the delay

Comment: Thanks again for the help. Here is the link to the new trace: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtOdmtev4QgBwSWfLGvNtcIuMfjO

Comment: have you used the windows 10 compression on the 850 Evo SSD to get more space? I see the WOF.sys involved a lot (Wof.sys!FileProvReadCompressed). Also do a [defrag of the SSD, this is sometimes good](https://superuser.com/a/1150677/174557), your SSD is fragmented with 17%. also remove  "Acronis Virtual Disk Storage Filter" (vidsflt.sys) and look if improves boot. also clear old restore points, I also see volsnap.sys calls

Comment: There is no compression on the 850 SSD and I just did a defrag and saw not improvement in boot times. Next I will attempt to remove Acronis Virtual Disk Storage Filter (I tried last night but the system wouldn't reboot after, so I had to do a restore).

Comment: uninstall Acronis completely and look if this improves boot.

Comment: I uninstalled Acronis but the problem still persists. However, I have noticed something interesting. If I restart (Start->restart)  the computer I am seeing the 300 second boot times, but if I shutdown (Start->Shutdown) and then press the power button to start the PC my boot time drops to 35 seconds. Any thoughts on why this would be the case?

Comment: Ok, false alarm, the speedy boot was due to the 'Fast Boot' option located under power options. Here is the latest trace. https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtOdmtev4QgBwS0kdRBkIrcO8WTp  Do you see anything new?

Comment: I still habe no real idea. run wprui and only select CPU + Registry IO. Here I also see Registry activity.

Comment: Here is the latest: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtOdmtev4QgBwS8VYrJ4INYv5CTC

Comment: do you use bitlocker? I see a large delay after opening the key **\HKLM\software\Microsoft\WINDOWS\CurrentVersion\BitLocker\overrides**

Comment: No I don't use bitlocker. I just checked and that key doesn't exist in my registry.

Comment: Solved. It was the Marvel 91xx SATA 6G Controller driver.I used the free version of Driver Easy to scan my system and it found that driver was out of date. As soon as I updated it my reboot time went down to 30 seconds, 20 of which are consumed between POST and the Windows icon, once I see the windows icon it takes less than 10 seconds before I see my desktop.

Comment: I checked the trace again and never see the marvel driver in any long waits.  Post it as answer which includes the old and the new driver version.

Comment: Here is the new trace after updating the marvel storage controller. https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtOdmtev4QgBwTRV-l-e6wZNK8eK

Comment: yes, boot is now faster, the delay is gone. now I see the loading of the driver, the old traces missed this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. It was the Marvel 91xx SATA 6G Controller driver.I used the free version of Driver Easy to scan my system and it found that driver was out of date. As soon as I updated it my reboot time went down to 30 seconds, 20 of which are consumed between POST and the Windows icon, once I see the windows icon it takes less than 10 seconds before I see my desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [ETL with Windows Performance Analyzer (WPA.exe)](https://superuser.com/a/1205327/174557) shows indeed that SMSSInit/Boot-SessionInit-Phase is taking the longest time with 211 seconds:

[image]

Drag & drop of the Generic Events graph shows that the that the task `InitializeRegistry` is the slowest part:

[image]

Make a full backup and try a registry cleaner tool (which I normally wan't recommend, but try it).