# Disk cleanup stuck on Windows Update

Tags: windows, windows-update, disk-cleanup

Whenever do Windows update cleanup in disk cleanup, the disk cleanup utility freezes up while that task (Windows Update cleanup) is running. Task Manager shows low resource usage. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Perhaps not stuck but a duplicate of this? https://superuser.com/questions/847556/why-does-disk-cleanup-take-so-much-time-and-cpu?rq=1

Comment: My situation is different. I don’t have high cpu utilization during this process.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it is not frozen up: A "Windows update cleanup" on a rotating disk can take many hours, if not a day or two. A less than powerfull CPU can also make a big difference.

I have seen it running on a Laptop 5400RPM disk running for 29 hours without any appreciable change on the progress bar.

Check your task manager and IO stats for activity by Cleanup Manager, Windows modules installer and Windows update service.

Comment: Even on my Surface with solid state, it would do the same thing. I do Disk Cleanup and Disk Defragmentation regularly.

Comment: On an SSD machine, Disk Cleanup and select Cleanup System files should be done within 30 minutes or so. Cancel out, restart and try again as restarting can help this

Comment: I would do that, when I had my Surface, but that didn’t fix the problem.

Comment: Delete what you can from Windows\Software Distribution\download, restart, update Windows fully, and then restart again and try Disk Cleanup. This is something we use at clients and it normally completes fine